# changing excel sheet content depending on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to build a dynamic checklist on Excel. The fields (rows) that the user must check will show up depending on the value of another cell (actually a dropdown menu in a cell).

This value can be option1, option2 or option3. Each option will have a different set of information to check. This set of information will show up in the same sheet.

How can I do that? I searched and found nothing helpful...

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. You want the value of one cell to equal the the resulting value of a drop-down menu?

Comment: Have you looked into doing this using VBA and userforms?

Comment: @CharlieRB A different choosen value from the dropdown menu shows a different table in another section of the same sheet...

Comment: So, if I choose "option 1", the table from somewhere else is copied to that same sheet the drop-down in on? Where are the tables of items kept? To be able to offer a solution it would be helpful to know what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. The tables are on another sheet and when I choose an option from the dropdown menu the corresponding table shows up in the dropdown menu's sheet.
I'm using Excel 2010